# Why can’t I properly select something without shading options popping up?

Tags: shaders, selection-tools, osx

I’m new to blender & have a Mac if that matters but I’m haveing troubles with selection. Without knowing how to properly select I dont know how to move forward in learning the program. I try to select items, move things around or use certain tools and as soon as I click .. the viewport shading options appear. I can’t move the center point or anything because every time I click it comes up with viewport shading options.(wideframe, renderview, solid material) It’s frustrating me. Pleassseeee help!!!

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is the shading preview "pie menu". Not sure why that's popping up after clicks. Try having a look at your keymaps in user preferences under `3D View > 3D View Tool: Tweak`. "Select" should be assigned to left mouse. You can also look in `3D View > 3D View (Global) > Shading` (it's right near the bottom of the global list) - this is the setting for the shading "pie menu" - see what it's set to.

Comment: Hi. Please don't ask the same question twice. Instead, you should address the issues with the original question by editing it. This will put the question into a review queue where it can be voted on to be reopened. Thanks.